# Updating a buffered image from a background thread

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, graphics, bufferedimage

I am creating and updating a BufferedImage on a background thread. The image is then drawn onto a JPanel by overriding the panels paint method as shown.

```
@Override
public void paint(Graphics g) {
    g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, null);
}
```

The background thread periodically updates the image then calls the panels invalidate method.

Will I run into any issues with this approach? Will the swing thread reading and the background thread updating the image cause any problems?

Thanks

Ben

Comment: it depends, if you're drawing (via AWT thread) at the same time when you're updating the image, then you have problems. Thread synchronization.

Comment: As an aside, "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks).

Comment: 1) In addition to what trashgod was mentioning, note that the `null` parameter passed as the last argument to `drawImage` is an `ImageObserver`.  Since `JPanel implements ImageObserver`, it should be `g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);`.  2) Unless you are stretching the image to fill that panel, or adding other components on top, I'd use a `JLabel` to display it. 3) If stretching the image, but **not** overlaying components, render in a `JComponent`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two threads *must* synchronize access to the shared data. [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingWorker.html) is the most reliable approach with which to periodically publish the `BufferedImage`; there's an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4637725/230513) using `Double`. You might also look at the example [here](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/threadwatch), which relies on the (implicit) ordering afforded by he `EventQueue` and `repaint()`. In either case, the limiting factor is the timer frequency relative to the repaint time.

Comment: What I ended up doing was creating a copy of the image in the background thread. The JPanel implements a callback interface which the background thread calls passing the copy. The JPanel then uses `SwingUtilities.invokeLater` to set the JPanel into a variable and call repaint on its self.